# Windows 7 - BSOD at every boot

Tags: windows, bsod

I have a laptop with Windows 7 that was originally installed with Windows XP. I'm pretty sure that its the video card drivers that are causing the problem. I was getting errors with `x000000428` not being signed correctly at first, but now I just get either `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` or `PAGE_IN_NON_PAGED_AREA`. When I boot with safe mode, I also get the same errors. I would re install W7, but I can't boot from the CD/DVD drive or from my 8gb jump drive. What can I do???

Comment: Can you get into your BIOS? If you can, then you can configure the boot order of devices on your computer to boot from CD or USB first, before it tries to boot from the hard drive. If you have the restore discs for your OS, then you could try repairing Windows 7 to see if that solves the issue.

Comment: ^ Like tk1974 says; a BSOD should have no effect on your ability to boot from CD/DVD or USB. Enter your BIOS setup screen and adjust the boot order, or some BIOSes also have a shortcut key that directly takes you to a boot menu. What kind of laptop do you have?

Comment: What I meant was I couldn't use them because I didn't have the drivers for the DVD drive, but I had no idea why I couldn't change it to boot to external, it just asked yo boot to CD after. I have a Compaq nx9010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have another working computer you could install from the [same HDD](http://www.instructables.com/id/Install-Windows-7-without-USB-or-DVD-without-upgra/)